# Create post with photograph in it but which shares as a "post" not as a "photo"

Tags: facebook, facebook-pages

I want to be able to have reviews be posted to a FB page and the post include a graphic of how many stars the review was for.  When doing this by uploading a photo of the stars and typing in the review, that goal is accomplished, but the second piece is that when someone shares the review, it doesn't show the icon of the page and also says that a photo was shared instead of a post.

Is there any way to have the image of the 5 stars being embedded inline in a normal post or some other way to make it be a normal post?

### Here's one example

[image: no stars]

### Here's the other example

[image: 5 stars]

Comment: You probably have to check the permissions for the photos you upload or use in your review post. Check if the photo has Public view permissions. Then check again if it is appearing when someone shares the review post that contains that photo.

Comment: It's not really a permission issue, but just how it displays differently when a photo is involved.